# Strategy for reading a tab delimited file and separating file for array with attr_reader

Tags: ruby

Trying to take a simple test.txt file and separate the text and integers after its read in for array manipulation. The idea is to be able to use/require the attr_accessor from the separate Person class.
So I can use :name, :hair_color, :gender

For example lets says we have in our text file which is all separated by the tab delimiter, for shortness I just used space:

```
Bob red_hair 38
Joe brown_hair 39
John black_hair 40
```

My class would read something like:

```
 class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :hair_color, :gender


   def initialize
    @place_holder = 'test'
   end

   def to_s
    @test_string = 'test a string'
   end
 end
```

My main file that I'm having strategy issues with so far:

```
 test_my_array = File.readlines('test.txt').each('\t')  #having trouble with
```

I'm pretty sure its easier to manipulate line by line rather then one file. I'm not sure where to go after that. I know I need to separate my data some how for :name, :hair_color, :gender. Throw some code up so I can try things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your `initialize` method accept values for `name`, `hair_color` and `gender`, you can do it like this:

```
my_array = File.readlines('test.txt').map do |line|
  Person.new( *line.split("\t") )
end
```

If you can't modify your `initialize` method, you'll need to call the writer methods one by one like this:

```
my_array = File.readlines('test.txt').map do |line|
  name, hair_color, gender = line.split("\t")
  person = Person.new
  person.name = name
  person.hair_color = hair_color
  person.gender = gender
  person
end
```

The easiest way to make initialize accept the attributes as argument without having to set all the variables yourself, is to use `Struct`, which shortens your entire code to:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :hair_color, :gender)
my_array = File.readlines('test.txt').map do |line|
  Person.new( *line.split("\t") )
end
#=> [ #<struct Person name="Bob", hair_color="red_hair", gender="male\n">,
#     #<struct Person name="Joe", hair_color="brown_hair", gender="male\n">,
#     #<struct Person name="John", hair_color="black_hair", gender="male\n">,
#     #<struct Person name="\n", hair_color=nil, gender=nil>]
```

Comment: I forgot about .map, doh! Thanks for the help!